# Tutorial for OpenDS to substitute Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a tutorial to substitute Microsoft Active Directory with OpenDS? DNS should have the information for LDAP and I would like to see how a Windows box should be configured to connect successfully to OpenDS.

Comment: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO#Video_demonstrations_of_this_HOWTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat complex problem as it is a bundle of Kerberos, LDAP, DNS, and more needed to get it all working together.

Novell has a product called DSFW (Domain Services for Windows) that allows eDirectory to interact with AD like it were part of the domain.  It is a mashup of all the needed parts.

Comment: And there's Samba4. And FreeIPA.

Comment: @patman yes probably they are the only solution. I am not sure about Samba management tools. Samba ha been alwasys to cumbersome to sue especially as DC. FreeIPA, at least, has a management console. I am not sure if MDS can be compared with FeeIPA

Answer (score 2):

AD is more than just an LDAP server. OpenDS doesn't completely replace it.

Comment: That's why I asked that question. It seems strange that there is not a documented solution to substitute AD using opends

Comment: Samba4 is trying to be an AD replacement.